# Checkbox "checked" not toggling correctly

Tags: knockout.js

when I check the checkbox, the status changes successfully(ajax call is successful and DB reflects the chnage), the span below also shows "CHECK" but the checkbox does not get toggled, so something is not working right with the "checked" attribute. What am I missing here.

```
<!-- ko foreach: Group-->
<tr>
  <td>
    <span data-bind="text: TourName "></span>
  </td>
  <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->

  <td style="vertical-align:middle" data-bind="attr: { rowspan: $parent.Group().length }">

    <!-- ko if: $parent.Status() != 'DNB' -->
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ($parent.Status() === 'CHECK'),click: $root.editSellStatus.bind($parent)" />
    <span data-bind="text: $parent.Status()"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->

  </td>

  <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This is my edit method:

```
self.editStatus = function() {
  var Status = null;

  if (this.Status() == 'CHECK') {
    this.Status(null);
    Status = null;
  } else if (this.Status() == null) {
    this.Status('CHECK');
    Status = 'CHECK';
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "SaveStatus/?ID=" + this.Id() + "&Status=" + Status,
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(result) {
      if (result == "success") {}
      self.selectedItem(null);
    }
  });

  var test = this.Status();
}
```

My KO model structure is something like this.

```
class MyClass {
  Name: string;
  year: string;
  Group: Array<{
    GroupName: string;
    Status: string;
    subGroup: Array<{....}>;
  }>;
}
```

Comment: Need your KO model, and your binding, and all the relevant html.  This is barely enough enough to know what's going on.

Comment: You're missing a [MCVE] to start with. Please post all the **relevant code**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using a click binding on a checkbox you're overriding the default click behavior which is to update the checkbox with a check-mark. To allow the browser to continue with the default behavior your click event function must return a true value.

```
self.editStatus = function() {
    ...
    return true;
}
```

```js
//This is my edit method:
self.editStatus = function() {
  var Status = null;

  if (this.Status() == 'CHECK') {
    this.Status(null);
    Status = null;
  } else if (this.Status() == null) {
    this.Status('CHECK');
    Status = 'CHECK';
  }
 
  //$.ajax()
  
  var test = this.Status();
  return true;
}

//My KO model structure is something like this.
function MyClass() {
  var self = this;
  this.Name = "Name";
  this.Id = "Id";
  this.year = 1999;
  this.Status = ko.observable(null);
  this.isChecked = ko.observable(false);
  this.Group = ko.observableArray([{
    GroupName: "Group 1",
    TourName: "Tour 1",
    Status: "Status",
    subGroup: [{
      //empty object
    }],
  }, {
    GroupName: "Group 2",
    TourName: "Tour 2",
    subGroup: [{
      //empty object
    }]
  }
  ]);

  this.editSellStatus = editStatus;
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyClass());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tbody>
  <!-- ko foreach: Group-->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span data-bind="text: TourName "></span>
    </td>
    <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->

    <td style="vertical-align:middle" data-bind="attr: { rowspan: $parent.Group().length }">

      <!-- ko if: $parent.Status() != 'DNB' -->
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ($parent.Status() === 'CHECK'),click: $root.editSellStatus.bind($parent)" />
      <span data-bind="text: $parent.Status()"></span>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </td>

    <!-- /ko -->
  </tr>
  <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(Status)"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. That did it!